# Find the largest even number which cannot be expressed as the sum of two odd composite numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ques -  Find the largest even number which cannot be expressed as the sum of two odd composite numbers.

Honestly speaking , I don't even know where to start . It would be great if someone could show me the way forward . Thanking in advance

Answer (score 5):

Let $n$ be an even number, hence $n$ is $0\pmod 6$ or $2\pmod 6$ or $4\pmod 6$.

Any number of the form $9+6k$ is composite for $k\ge 0$ (as it divisible by $3$).

Now, if $n\ge 18$ and $n\equiv 0\pmod 6$ we can write $n=9+(9+6k)$, i.e $n$ is sum of two odd composite numbers.

If $n\ge 44$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod 6$ we can write $n=35+(9+6k)$, i.e $n$ is sum of two odd composite numbers.

If $n\ge 34$ and $n\equiv 4\pmod 6$ we can write $n=25+(9+6k)$, i.e $n$ is sum of two odd composite numbers.

All we need to check are the numbers $38,40,42$. The last two are covered, but $38$ doesn't, thus it is the largest even number which is not a sum of two odd composite numbers.

Comment: Note that Anatoly's answer, which at first sight looks pretty different from this, is actually the same argument in disguise, but combining the cases 2 and 4 mod 6 into a single case mod 5.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution: let us call $k $ the largest integer that cannot be written as a sum of two odd composite numbers. By definition, $k-j $, (where $j $ is a composite odd number $<k $) must be prime. Now let us consider the quantities 
$$k-3 \cdot 3=k-9$$
$$k-3 \cdot 5=k-15$$ 
$$k-3 \cdot 7=k-21$$ 
$$k-3 \cdot 9=k-27$$ 
$$k-3 \cdot 11=k-33$$

If there exists a value of $k>33$, they have all to be prime or equal to $1$. Now we can note that one of these five numbers must necessary be divisible by $5$ (since they are in aritmetic progression with common difference $6$ ). Thus, the only possibility is given by $k-33=5$. This leads to a maximal value of $k $ equal to $38$.

Comment: Can you pls explain your answer in simple words ? I understood why k - j should be prime , but couldn't understand why we are taking those quantities .

Comment: @AnirudhaBrahma What Anatoly's doing is looking at the possible small (odd composite) values of j. Most of these will have 3 as a factor (since otherwise the smallest prime factor would have to be at least 5, and so j itself would have to be $5 \cdot 5$, $5 \cdot 7$ or something larger); conversely, $3 \cdot (2n+1)$ is always odd and composite (for $n > 0$). [Continued below]

Comment: Now, if $j$ is divisible by 3 and so is $k$, then $k - j$ will automatically be a multiple of 3 as well and so, for large enough $j$, it will be a sum of two odd composite numbers. On the other hand, if $k$ is not divisible by 3 but $j$ still is, then $k - j$ cannot be divisible by 3. Since it is still odd, its smallest prime factor must be at least 5. So if we can find a list of small values of $j$ such that at least one of the $k - j$ must be divisible by 5, then we're essentially done.

Comment: Finally, note that any arithmetic sequence of length $p$ (prime), with successive differences not a multiple of $p$, must contain a multiple of $p$ - this is the bit using modular arithmetic. In this case, the 5-term sequence $k - 33, k - 27, k - 21, k - 15, k - 9$ has successive differences of 6 and so must contain at least one multiple of 5. Unless that number is 5 itself, it will be composite; and since $k$ was even and $j$ was odd, $k - j$ will also be odd.

Comment: I read only now the further question on why we are taking those quantities.  Thank you very much to Robin for his comments (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Any even number greater than 38 can be expressed as the sum of two odd composite numbers.

According to OEIS sequence [A118081](https://oeis.org/A118081), the even numbers that can't be represented as the sum of two odd composite numbers are:
$$ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 22, 26, 28, 32, 38.$$

Comment: Actually, you can't write 38 as a sum of two odd composite numbers.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks!